# Get the largest and smallest number from a array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, winforms

I’m using `WinForms`. At first I was having a hard time adding data from textbox to an array, but I figured it out, but I don’t know if this is the ideal way to do it. Next, what I’m trying to do is get the largest number in the array and the smallest number in the array except of zero. In my example, I typed in 2, 5, 8, 7, 6 7. For this example, my goal is to get the numbers 2 and 7 back. 2 being the smallest number in the array besides 0, and 7 being the largest number in the array

So far i have this.

```
private const int MAX_ITEMS = 10;
private int[] numArray = new int[MAX_ITEMS];
private int index = 0;

private void Add_Data_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.index < numArray.GetUpperBound(0))
    {
        int dnum;
        if (int.TryParse(i_richTextBox1.Text, out dnum))
        {
            numArray[this.index++] = dnum;
            i_richTextBox1.Text = "";
        }

        if (Value_Out_Array_CheckBx.Checked == true)
        {
            foreach (var item in numArray)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.min(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.max(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you everybody. I got to practice my arrays and Linq some more :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After understanding that what you want is to get **one** number at each press of the button and that **each time** you want to calculate the Min and Max I suggest:

```
private List<int> _numbers = new List<int>(); // Use List<int> to avoid having irrelevant 0 items

private int _min;
private int _max;

private void Add_Data_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Parse and add new number to collection (notice - this does not take care of invalid input..
    var number = int.Parse(i_richTextBox1.Text);

    // If it is the first time iterating then this number is both the _min and _max
    if(_numbers.Count == 0)
    {
        _min = number;
        _max = number;
    }
    else
    {
        //Check if need to update _min or _max
        if(number < _min)
            _min = number;
        else if(number > max)
            _max = number;
    }

    _numbers.Add(number);
}
```

*Of course you can still use linq `.Min` and `Max` operations on the collection to check for the updated values but why do an `o(2n)` when you can `2x o(n)`*

---

Answer **before** understanding latest comment:

> To deal with the `0` problem:

You can use Linq `Except` or check that the item isn't `0` when looking for Min and Max but I'd just suggest changing from an `int[10]` to a `List<int>` - That way you won't have those empty items.

If it is a list then each time the button is pressed:

```
private void Add_Data_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    numberList.Add(int.Parse(i_richTextBox1.Text));
}
```

> Getting Min and Max:

Use linq:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int> {2, 5, 8, 7, 6 7};
var min = numbers.Min();
var max = numbers.Max();
```

Or if you want to do it in `o(n)` instead of `o(2n)`:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int> {2, 5, 8, 7, 6 7};
int min = numbers[0];
int max = numbers[0];

foreach(item in numbers)
{
    if(item > max)
        max = item;
    else if(item < min)
        min = item;
}
```

> Change way of getting numbers:

If you want to change the way you get the data from the `TextBox` and get it all at once (instead of one number at a time) then use `string.Split`:

```
string data = "2 5 8 7 6 7";
var numbers = data.Split(' ')
                  .Select(int.Parse).ToList();

// Or if you might have more spaces:
string data = "2  5 8 7   6 7";
var numbers = data.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                  .Select(int.Parse).ToList();
```

---

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wanted to add the numbers from my textbox then get the min and max value.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wanted to add the data into the array every time I click on the button from my textbox then get the min and max value. For example, first if I type in 2 then I click button now the array holds 2.  Then I type in 5 then, I click button now the array holds 2 and 5. Lastly, I type in 9 then I click button, now the array holds 2, 5 and 9. Then I want to get the min and max data from the array.

Comment: @taji01 - wait - do you want to get the numbers one at a time at each press? And do you want each time to calculate the new min and max?

Comment: Yes that is what im looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

instead of getting numbers one by one you can read all the numbers at once. And using Regex and Linq

```
var numbers = Regex.Matches(i_richTextBox1.Text, @"\d+")
                .Cast<Match>()
                .Select(m=>int.Parse(m.Value))
                .ToArray();
var min = numbers.Min();
var max = numbers.Max();
```

For ex, type `2 3 4 61 7 12` to your textbox..

Comment: Thanks. This is almost what i wanted but i wanted to add my numbers one by one inside my textbox then get the min and max.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to get the minimum except `0`, you can use:

```
var min = numArray.Except(new int[] { 0 }).Min();
```

or

```
var min = numArray.Where(x => x != 0).Min();
```

And for the maximum, as mentioned by Gilad too:

```
var max = numArray.Max();
```

Be aware of an `InvalidOperationException` saying `Sequence contains no elements`, if the `numArray` contains no element of just a `0`.

Comment: Based on your recent questions, I believe it's time to learn more about linq. It makes your programming life easier ;)